# MongoDB group by day with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, date, morphia

I have a MongoDB which stores simple Pojo with Morphia:

```
@Entity
private static class Task{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private Date timestamp;
    private int task;
}
```

What I want to do is get the total number of tasks for each day. I came to the problem with handling the date so that they will be project to a day(01-07-2015 00:00:00:00)  instead of a full date with seconds and miliseconds.

Possible solutions:

1. For each day I have to do a separate aggregation, which I'd rather not do.
2. From this [link](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework) I came up with the idea of having a function like

   > (timestamp.toMilliseconds() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toDate()

so that the days would be rounded, but I'm not sure how to do it with Morphia and java. I'm quite new to this and still looking for a way to do operations with the date, but there is very few useful tutorial online.

3. Project the timestamp to 3 columns of year, month and day and then do some grouping. But the idea of having 3 column just for a day is really not enjoyable for me.

Please help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I am able to find out something, it is about the second method.
Since mongo does not support operation like timestamp.toMilliseconds(), I need to get each component of the date and calculate them to miliseconds just like the [link](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework) mentioned.

```
    Projection ms = expression("$millisecond", projection("timestamp"));
    Projection secToMs = multiply(expression("$second", projection("timestamp")), SEC_TO_MS);
    Projection minToMs = multiply(expression("$minute", projection("timestamp")), MIN_TO_MS);
    Projection hourToMs = multiply(expression("$hour", projection("timestamp")), H_TO_MS);
    Projection sum = add(ms, secToMs, minToMs, hourToMs);
    Projection dayRounded = subtract(projection("timestamp"), sum);
```

And then what I left to do is just

```
datastore.createAggregation(Task.class).project(projection("timestamp",dayRounded)).aggregate(OutputClass.Class);
```

Hope that will be useful for someone. If anyone find a better sollution please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a new field: `int daycode` which you populate as `20150701` when setting the `timestamp` field in the application layer. Then you can do aggregation with no calculations at all. Furthermore you can put an index on this `daycode` field and later you have the option to shard the collection on this field.

In the document-database world you want to avoid doing on-the-fly calculations at all costs and pre-calculate as much as possible. It may look redundant but you'll save CPU cycles in the long term.

Comment: I did some last tests and the query actually didn't take too long so I think it's fine for now. But surely your idea makes sense and I will consider it, thank you very much for your input:)